# Is Bravura financial bank is a legit bank?

Tags: scams

They created an USD account under my name and encash the cheque. Ask to pay TAC CODE, TAX CODE Via BITCOIN WALLET. while completing the international transfers i was prompted to enter IMF CODE AND COT CODE. Is this a scam,? thank you

Answer (score 6):

Of course it is a scam.

1. Real banks would never allow anyone to create a bank account under the name of someone else. That would violate about a hundred banking regulations.
2. Real banks will never demand to be paid so you can *receive* money. They will only demand payment under some circumstances when you *send* money.
3. Real banks will not ask you to jump through any other hoops to receive a payment. When someone transferred money to you, it will just appear in your account.
4. Real banks will not demand payment for any services via Bitcoins or other third-party pamyent providers. Real banks *are* payment providers, so they have no need for those. They will take money in cash, via wire transfer or just take it from your account.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is a scam 100%. Paying for weird transaction fees is a well known scam.

Answer (score 4):

COT codes are *always* a scam.

More importantly the [Bravura Financials](https://www.godaddy.com/whois/results.aspx?domain=bravuafinancials.com) "bank" web site was only created three months ago:

[image]