# Is a tcp code fee a legit fee what is a tcp code

Tags: scams, international-transfer

I was told that I have a account with a bank "Ashdean Bank". I never heard of that bank, and a Google search came up with nothing.

I was told that a fee needs to be paid to obtain a "tcp code", which would be needed in order to make a transfer from the UK to my bank in the USA. These people want a lot of money for that fee. Reading this as I write it, it sounds pretty stupid to me. But you never know.

Comment: Interesting. Seems the scammers found that too many Google hits for "COT code" lead to scam warnings now, so they renamed it to "TCP code". Probably because TCP is already a well-established acronym so it is much harder to google.

Comment: Related question: [Is Bravura financial bank is a legit bank?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/156517/is-bravura-financial-bank-is-a-legit-bank/)

Answer (score 10):

Anytime somebody wants you to pay money to get your money, it is a scam.

In your case they want you to pay money to get money you never knew about. That also means it is a scam.

If there was a legitimate fee, they would just deduct it from the money being sent to you.

Comment: That's the most common sense point: If anyone wanted to give you money but there are legitimate fees (which just about _might_ happen), they will subtract that fee from the money they sent you. That lottery you never heard of would just pay you $999,000 instead of paying you $1,000,000 after you paid them a $1,000 fee.