# LMS Code for making international transfer

Tags: banking, scams, international-transfer, fraud, online-banking

I have been asked to make advance payment of 85 usd for LMS code inorder to make international wire transfer. Why are they not deducting. Could this be a scam attempt by the bank.
The bank is unifiedfalcon.xyz. Anyone please can you help me vaidate where this is a scam or is legit?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a tcp code fee a legit fee what is a tcp code](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/159261/is-a-tcp-code-fee-a-legit-fee-what-is-a-tcp-code)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I was asked for a COT code to transfer money to my account. Is this a scam?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/100166/i-was-asked-for-a-cot-code-to-transfer-money-to-my-account-is-this-a-scam)

Answer (score 7):

This is clearly a scam. Please be aware that anyone can set up a web site claiming to be a bank. This web site is clearly bogus:

1. Googling "United Falcon" reveals several non-banking businesses in the middle east, but no sign of a bank by that name in the UK.
2. Several of the links on the home page are dead or simply link back to the home page. In particular, the link to "Terms of Use" at the bottom of the home page just links back to the home page. Any real business would make sure that link was working.
3. The "Contact" link at the bottom of the home page shows an address of "10030 brick lane, United kingdom". This isn't how an actual address would be written in the UK. There would at least be a city and a postal code. Also note that there are no phone numbers listed.
4. No list of corporate officers is provided.
5. No links are provided to relevant UK government banking authorities or regulations.
6. It's using the .xyz domain. Legitimate banks in the UK would almost certainly be using the .co.uk domain. The .xyz domain is notorious for hosting scams.

It's not a real bank and is trying to scam  you.